# How to solve prestashop infinite redirection loop under ssl?

Tags: ssl, prestashop

Don't know, maybe someone had the same problem before..

I've got a correctly configured ssl certificate in my server.
If I activate prestashop ssl mode, then several pages generate an infinite redirection loop warning....

I really can't figure out why..
One thing I can say, is that in backoffice, clicking on the ssl acivation link, it does not activate it: it stays, silently, no rerrors, nothing.
So to activate ssl I had to manually change the relevant config variable on the DB.

This could maybe be a symptom of something wrong on the server?

Anyone had the same problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from upgrading to v1.6.0.11, the solution was to add `SetEnv HTTPS On` at the very top of .htaccess. That's because several prestashop functions rely on `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and/or `$_SERVER['SSL']` vars to guess the urls. One of the most notable functions using them and itself used by many others is Tools::usingSecureMode(). Simply those vars weren't visible before adding `SetEnv HTTPS On`.

Anyway, this is not to be considered a universal solution, because for example in my local MAMP installation I didn't have the same issue: just worked. I only needed the tweak for the remote server.

Beside this, also note that in backoffice, unde url/seo prefs, I disabled the apache multiviews.

Hope it helps